# How to remove All Groups with Exceptions by using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've seen many examples of using PS to remove all memberships (including Primary). I have working code as follows:

```
get-aduser person -properties MemberOf | Select -Expand MemberOf | %{Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -member person -confirm:$false}
```

This is great for stripping everything out, excluding Domain Users. No problems so far.

The next challenge is leaving behind a specific group, such as licensing for O365.

I attempted to build an array with exclusions, and excluding those from the removal:

```
$user = person
$keep = @(
'CN=nametokeep,OU=group,DC=company,DC=com',
'CN=nametoalsokeep,OU=group,DC=company,DC=com')

$groups = get-aduser person -properties memberof | select -expand memberof

$groups | %{$keep -notcontains $_} | Remove-ADGroupMember -member $user
```

The idea here is to define the exceptions and remove everything else that doesn't match up.

When I do this, the code does execute but prompts for input:

```
Members[0]:
```

Doesn't matter what value I put in there, the code just prompts again with Members[1], Members[2] and so on.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps

What you are missing is that the `-member` parameter you are attempting to use does not exist at all... When powershell prompt for input like that, often this is because you did not provide a mandatory parameter. In the current case, the cmdlet expect values to be passed to a mandatory `-members` parameter.(not `-member`)

Comment: That's what I thought too with -members as per the documentation, but instead I get

```
Remove-ADGroupmember : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:12 char:36
+ ... groups | %{$keep -notcontains $_} | Remove-ADGroupmember -members $user
```

I would expect the working code to throw an error if this was the issue.

Ending at -notcontains enumerates with True/False.

Comment: Ah ok... Looks like you want to remove a single user from multiple groups rather than multiple users from a single group. Hold on...

Comment: Yeah, instead of a foreach, you want to use a `where` statement. Your foreach give you true or false but you don't really care about the `True`, you care about the actual records that are true, hence `where` use. I submitted an answer that I believe correspond to what you seek to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove "person" from all the groups not in the keep array, you will need to do a Foreach on each of the groups out of the `$keep` array so you iterate through them.

Also, `Remove-ADGroupMember` does not have a `-Member` parameter.
Parameter is `-Members` and that's what your powershell prompt is asking about when you run the cmdlet without it's mandatory parameter.

The following script should accomplish what you seek.

```
$user = 'Person'
$keep = @(
'CN=nametokeep,OU=group,DC=company,DC=com',
'CN=nametoalsokeep,OU=group,DC=company,DC=com'
)

$groups = get-aduser -Identity $user -properties memberof | select -expand memberof

$groups.Where({$_ -notin ($keep)}) |
% { Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $user}
```

**Reference**

[Remove-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps)

Comment: This is exactly it; awesome! Very curious about the -members parameter. Will have to double check what I believe to be working code now. Better to find out now than when needed, right? Legendary; thank you!